# Variable Range Used for a Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded the below code for use in my macro, but it would only be useful if that range never changes.

Because the range does change each time I run it, how can I change "A1:E2" into variables to account for a changing range?

I don't think `xlLastCell` would be a correct usage in this case.

I know how to get the column number and row number of the ending cell, but I couldn't figure out how to incorporate that into my code.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1:E2").Select 
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
```

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to get zeros in every cell until the xllastcell?

Comment: This could be sum up as `ActiveCell.Range("A3:E4").Formula = "0"` or if you are trying to replace everything in your sheet by a 0, you could use `UsedRange.Formula = "0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know how to get the column number and row number of the ending cell, but I couldn't figure out how to incorporate that into my code.

Like this:

```
Dim myRange as Range
Set myRange = Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
```

In the above code, `myRange` is defined by two cells, one at (1,1) (row 1, column 1) and another at (lastRow, lastColumn) which would be the vairables you identifed as the ending row/column.

Comment: Thanks @David Zemens that helped a lot! Below is my variation of your code which gives me the variable range I need.    `Dim myRange As Range`    `Application.Goto Reference:="Beginning_Month"`  
    `wsBeginning_Zeroes_Row = wsBeginning_Date_Row + 2`  
    `wsEnding_Zeroes_Row = wsBeginning_Date_Row + 3`  
    
    `Set myRange = Range(Cells(wsBeginning_Zeroes_Row, wsBeginning_Date_Column), Cells(wsEnding_Zeroes_Row, wsNew_Date_Column - 1))`  
    `myRange.FormulaR1C1 = "0"`